# Trying to make a video player with and List

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, arraylist, video

I've made a an list with Videoclips, I noticed it's different to make than an array of audioclips which i made earlier. I tried different ways to code it but end up with no clues.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class TVChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<VideoClip> Videolist;
    public int Maxvideos;
    public VideoPlayer Videoplayer;
    public KeyCode Change = KeyCode.E;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (CurrentVideo >= Maxvideos)
        {
            CurrentVideo = 0;
        }
    }

    public int CurrentVideo;
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(Change))
        {
            Videoplayer.clip(Videolist[CurrentVideo]);
            Videoplayer.Play();
            CurrentVideo += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s the question?

Comment: i'm having an error at

`Videoplayer.clip(Videolist[CurrentVideo]);`

"non-invocable member VideoPlayer.clip cannot be used like a method"

what i'm trying to create is a list of videos everytime you're in the trigger and press the "Change" key it goes to the next song in the list.

Comment: You need VideoPlayer.clip= and then to play it?

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. thanks alot

Comment: Always best to read the documentation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Simply reproduce your problem. the steps to make a simple video player with VIDEO PLAYER in UNITY:

1.First create a RawImage component and then create a Video Player below it.

2.Then create a new Render Texture and assign it to RawImage and Video Player.

3.Then put the video on the Video Player so you can play the video.

[image]

4.Then you can start adding playback pause buttons and forward and backward buttons to the video.

[image]

Then create the script code:

```
//Set VideoPlayer, RawImage and currently playing video index parameters
private VideoPlayer videoPlayer;
private RawImage rawImage;
private int currentClipIndex;
//Set related parameters and video list
public Text text_PlayOrPause;
public Button button_PlayOrPause;
public Button button_Pre;
public Button button_Next;
public VideoClip[] videoClips;

private void Start()
{
    //Get the VideoPlayr and RawImage components, and initialize the current video index
    videoPlayer = this.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
    rawImage = this.GetComponent<RawImage>();
    ///<summary>
    /// Initialize the current video index, I don't know why
    /// </summary>
    currentClipIndex = 0;

    //Set related button listener events
    button_PlayOrPause.onClick.AddListener(OnplayOrPauseVideo);
    button_Next.onClick.AddListener(onNextVideo);
    button_Pre.onClick.AddListener(OnPreVideo);
}

private void Update()
 //Here is to prevent null pointer exception, judge whether the texture is empty, jump out when empty, and then re-deliver the texture to the player
{
    if(videoPlayer.texture == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    rawImage.texture = videoPlayer.texture;
}
private void OnplayOrPauseVideo()
{
    //Here is to judge the playback status of the video, if it is playing, it will be paused, and vice versa;
    //then update the relevant text
    if(videoPlayer.isPlaying == true)
    {
        videoPlayer.Pause();
        text_PlayOrPause.text = "Play";
    }
    else
    {
        videoPlayer.Play();
        text_PlayOrPause.text = "Pause";
    }
}
///<summary>
///Switch to the previous video
///</summary>
private void OnPreVideo()
{
    currentClipIndex -= 1;//The video index is automatically decremented, minus one to play the previous video to avoid out-of-bounds operations
    if (currentClipIndex < 0)
    {
        currentClipIndex = videoClips.Length - 1;//If it is empty, assign it to the currently playing video minus one
    }
    videoPlayer.clip = videoClips[currentClipIndex];
    text_PlayOrPause.text = "Pause";
}
private void onNextVideo()
{//Auto increment first, then the number of the video playback is equal to the increment of the data just incremented by one, and then the text is output
    currentClipIndex += 1;
    currentClipIndex = currentClipIndex % videoClips.Length;//The remainder is also to wait for the traversal to start from the beginning! Otherwise, an error will be reported after traversing
    videoPlayer.clip = videoClips[currentClipIndex];
    text_PlayOrPause.text = "Pause";
}
```

Then add this code to the RawImage. The text can be added or not added. The three buttons are assigned to these three, and then the Video Clips below is to define several videos, and then add the videos one by one.

[image]

Then the button is solved, and then the problem of the slider is solved;
It is also necessary to create two Text texts first. I am taking these two names here.

[image]

Create two scripts first.

```
public VideoClip videoClip; //The file parameter of the video
public Text videoTimeText; //Video file txt file
public Slider videoTimeSlider; //The time of the video Slider
public Text videoNmaeText; //The name of the video
//Define parameters to get VideoPlayer component and RawImage component
public VideoPlayer videoPlayer;
private RawImage rawImage;

void Start()
{
    //Start getting the components in the scene
    videoPlayer = this.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
    rawImage = this.GetComponent<RawImage>();
    videoPlayer.clip = videoClip;//This is the currently playing video, you can find it in the canvas panel
    videoNmaeText.text = videoClip.name; //Assign the name
    clipHour = (int)videoPlayer.clip.length / 3600;
    clipMinute = (int)(videoPlayer.clip.length - clipHour * 3600) / 60;
    clipSecond = (int)(videoPlayer.clip.length - clipHour * 3600 - clipMinute *60);

    videoPlayer.Play();
}

void Update()
{
    //If the videoPlayer has no corresponding video texture, return
    if(videoPlayer.texture == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    rawImage.texture = videoPlayer.texture;
    ShowVideoTime();
}
/// <summary>
/// Display the current video time
/// </summary>
private void ShowVideoTime()
{
    //The playback time of the current 0 video
    currentHour = (int)videoPlayer.time / 3600;
    currentMinute = (int)(videoPlayer.time - currentHour * 3600) / 60;
    currentSecond = (int)(videoPlayer.time - currentHour * 3600 - currentMinute * 60);
    // Put the current playback time on the text? ? ? ?
    videoTimeText.text = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2} / {3:D2}:{4:D2}:{5:D2}", currentHour, currentMinute, currentSecond, clipHour, clipMinute, clipSecond);
    //Assign the time ratio of the current video playback to the Slider string.Format? ? ? ?
    videoTimeSlider.value = (float)(videoPlayer.time / videoPlayer.clip.length);
}
/// <summary>
/// Convert the current Slider scale value to the current video playback time? ? ? ? ?
/// </summary>
private void SetVideoTimeValueChange()
{
    videoPlayer.time = videoTimeSlider.value * videoPlayer.clip.length;
}
// Parameters of the total time value of the current video and the current playback time value
private int currentHour;
private int currentMinute;
private int currentSecond;
private int clipHour;
private int clipMinute;
private int clipSecond;
```

then the second script:

```
  [SerializeField] private ToPlayVideo toPlayVideo;//private definition variable video playback script
 /// <summary>
 /// Add drag event to Slider
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="eventData"></param>
 public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
 {
     Debug.Log("sdfdsf");
     SetVideoTimeValueChang();
 }
 /// <summary>
 /// The current Slider scale value is converted to the time of the currently playing video
 /// </summary>
 private void SetVideoTimeValueChang()
 {
    toPlayVideo.videoPlayer.time = toPlayVideo.videoTimeSlider.value * toPlayVideo.videoPlayer.clip.length;
 }
 // Start is called before the first frame update
 void Start()
 {
    
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
    
 }
```

Drag the first one to RawImage, and put the data inside.

[image]

[image]

The second is placed in the Slider.Simple video swipe done.Hope it helps you.